# Develop a facebook app tutorial

Tags: php, facebook

I'm pretty new to php but I would like to make a Facebook app, for a competition where the participants can send in their ideas. Does anyone know a good tutorial or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried googling for this? Or are we doing the work for you? ;)

Answer (score 24):

Here's a handful of links to tutorials that will more than likely be able to get you started:

- [Facebook PHP Tutorial](http://www.merchantos.com/makebeta/facebook/facebook-php-tutorial/)
- [Build Your First Facebook App](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/build-your-first-facebook-app/)
- [How To Build A Facebook Application](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/building_facebook_applications/)
- [Create a Facebook Application with PHP](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/create-a-facebook-application-with-php-8-01-05/page1.html)

In addition to having very relevant information on their own, a lot of these pages also host links to "further reading". This should provide you with plenty of material to get started. Once you begin developing and start to run into more specific questions, come on back to SO and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: +1 also, what about any tutorial apart from php?

Comment: Just google it men. Sigh.