# How to create a Facebook share link with return url?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-sharer

I would like to know how to make a Facebook share link, of which has a return value to go to a different page. I have read that, although still available, the Facebook Share button was deprecated when Facebook launched the like button and the Like button contains of the sum of likes, shares and messages of URL.

For this question I am using a different situation, of which is very much the same. Once the user clicks to share, it will open up a JQuery dialog with an iframe in side of the Facebook share. Upon the user clicking to share, I would like to know how to listen for this so I can add to my own custom share button with counter and then to also redirect to a different URL which offers on for them sharing our

I have created a basic Dialog with a button to open it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kbJ57/

```
<a href="#" id="open">Share This!</a>

<div id="dialog-message" title="Share on Facebook!">
        <p>iFrame goes here</p>
</div>
```

This this example, please just show something like Google after the user has shared and any random page to share if you are able to help out with programming this, and I thank you so very much if you do.

Best Regards,

Tim

**Edit:** Looking at a page of a game I play, there is a share button at the bottom so I gather you can still do shares, I'm just not sure how to. (the link: http://services.runescape.com/m=news/behind-the-scenes-april-2013 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to create a facebook app and integrate that into your website in order to do sharing.

See developers.facebook.com for more info. As far as I know there isn't an "easy" way to do facebook sharing as it requires that the user authorize you to post on their behalf.

EDIT: 
I misunderstood the intent of the asker initially.
Try using the facebook sharer:
www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= [the url you want to share properly escaped]

Format the metadata of your site using the opengraph tags to have facebook pick up the content.
Good details here:
http://alistapart.com/article/like-able-content-spread-your-message-with-third-party-metadata

Comment: I do not wish to post on their behalf, they click my share button and it shows the Facebook share page which they can choose to share or not alike this example: http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fservices.runescape.com%2Fm%3Dnews%2Fbehind-the-scenes-april-2013

Comment: That is what I would like, however I only know the basic content via sources I've come across, however I need to implement a return url, of which I cannot find if it exists or not

Comment: Updated my answer. I don't think you can do a return url without using the SDK which is app specific. 
You might be able to use javascript to redirect your page after submitting, but I've not used the facebook sharer to redirect before.

Comment: Also, here's a link showing how you could set a return url if you were using a facebook app and the SDK: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: Is Facebook the only one which requires an app id to have a return link do you know or does Twitter/Google+ require something similar?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Twitter requires similar, not sure about Google+

Comment: Could you kindly provide a link to how I would do so once I have an app_id if you wouldn't mind?

Comment: I've not used PHP (I'm a ruby dev) to make a facebook app yet, but facebook has an SDK for php development. Here is a SO question about how to make a PHP facebook app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340879/develop-a-facebook-app-tutorial